# restar salidas de entradas de productos mysql

Tags: sql

hola espero poder explicarme mediante los ejemplos como puedo hacer para restar todos mis productos salientes con los productos que tengo de entrada.

Tengo las siguientes "entradas" de productos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En total tengo en stock:

```
SELECT sku, talla, SUM(cantidad) FROM entradas GROUP BY sku, talla
sku | talla | cantidad
2   | 34    | 14
2   | 35    | 4
```

mis salidas son:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando consulte el producto debe quedar el siguiente resultado:

```
    codigo | talla | cantidad
    2      | 34    | 12
    2      | 35    | 2
```

tengo este ejemplo de consulta que se aproxima pero no logro hacer agrupar y restar a las entradas los productos salientes:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT sku, talla, SUM(cantidad) FROM entradas GROUP BY sku, talla
   UNION ALL
SELECT sku, talla, SUM(cantidad) FROM salidas GROUP BY sku, talla
) AS e WHERE sku = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He estado haciendo pruebas y esto funciona:

```
SELECT sku, talla, SUM(stock) AS stock
FROM
  (SELECT sku, talla, SUM(stock) AS stock FROM entradas GROUP BY sku, talla
    UNION ALL
   SELECT sku, talla, -SUM(stock) AS stock FROM salidas GROUP BY sku, talla
  ) as subquery
GROUP BY sku, talla;
```

Lo que estás haciendo aquí es seleccionar los campos que quieres y, en el sum(stock) seleccionamos el valor de una subquery donde indicamos que el sumatorio de stock es la suma de la entradas junto (UNION ALL) a la suma (negativa, por eso tiene -sum) de las salidas.

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: stock]

Comment: Genial puedo en la misma consulta obtener el valor de la entradas con el precio de la feche mas reciente ?

Comment: Disculpa, el valor de la entrada con el precio de la fecha más reciente? No entendí...

Comment: en mi tabla de entradas esta el valor del producto pero pueden cambiar según la talla o la fecha. Como puedo consultar también ese ultimo valor según la fecha mas reciente algo con MAX(entradas.fecha)

Comment: He añadido otra respuesta con el resultado del comentario. Si hay alguna duda, hazmela saber.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre la consulta referente a saber la fecha de entrada más reciente en función del tipo y talla, la consulta es esta

```
SELECT sku, talla, MAX(fecha) AS entrada_mas_reciente from entradas
GROUP BY sku, talla;
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: Fecha]